# jquery select element by name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an input with the name attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="data[foo][bar]" />
```

how can I select this element?

I tried `$("input[name=data[foo][bar]]")` but in vein.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add quotes to the attribute value, otherwise you get conflicting square brackets and a parse error:

```
$("input[name='data[foo][bar]']")
```

Comment: Yup, those quotes are actually [mandatory](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name='data[foo][bar]']")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name="data[foo][bar]"]')
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ for more info

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("input[name=data\\[foo\\]\\[bar\\]]")
```

The documentation says:

If you wish to use any of the meta-characters ( such as !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, you must escape the character with two backslashes: \. For example, if you have an element with id="foo.bar", you can use the selector $("#foo\.bar").

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/